# Role ARIA and accessibility elements <ul> <li <ol> or < menu>

Tags: menu, roles, blogger, menuitem, wai-aria

I'm creating a menu apparently everything is fine.Everything works. But it keeps showing an accessibility error.

List `<li>` items are not contained within parent `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` elements. Screen readers require list items `<li>`to be contained within a `<ul>`, `<ol>`, or `<menu>` parent element in order to be enunciated correctly.

What am I using:

```
    <div class='header-menu' role='menu'>
  <div class='mobile-menu'/>
  <div class='container row'>
    <span class='slide-menu-toggle'/>
    <b:section class='main-menu' id='main-menu' maxwidgets='1' name='Main Menu' role='menu' showaddelement='yes'>
      <b:widget id='LinkList74' locked='true' title='Link List' type='LinkList' version='2' visible='true'>
        <b:widget-settings>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-10'>_Web Doc</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='sorting'>NONE</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-1'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-2'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-12'>https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-0'>/</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-11'>https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-10'>.https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-9'>Documentation</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-9'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-8'>_Error Page</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-7'>https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-8'>https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-5'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-6'>https://www</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-3'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='link-4'>#</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-1'>Features</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-0'>Home</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-3'>__DropDown 1</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-2'>_Multi DropDown</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-5'>__DropDown 3</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-4'>__DropDown 2</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-7'>_SiteMap</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-6'>_ShortCodes</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-11'>_Video Doc</b:widget-setting>
          <b:widget-setting name='text-12'>Download This Template</b:widget-setting>
        </b:widget-settings>
        <b:includable id='main'>
          <b:include name='content'/>
        </b:includable>
        <b:includable id='content'>
          <ul id='main-menu-nav' role='menubar'>
            <b:loop values='data:links' var='link'>
              <li><a expr:href='data:link.target' role='menuitem'><data:link.name/></a></li>
            </b:loop>
          </ul>
        </b:includable>
      </b:widget>
    </b:section>
    <div id='nav-search'>
      <form class='search-form' expr:action='data:blog.searchUrl' role='search'>
        <input autocomplete='off' class='search-input' expr:placeholder='data:messages.searchThisBlog' name='q' type='search' value=''/>
        <span class='hide-search'/>
      </form>
    </div>
    <span class='show-search'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I resolve? This code is different from all the tutorials on the internet.

I also have a second question that seems to be easy but just turned into a monster.

The second error is this:

**Elements with an ARIA [role] that require children to contain a specific [role] do not have some or none of the required children. Some parent ARIA roles need to have specific child roles to fulfill their intended accessibility tasks.**

**Failed elements:

Home
Features
Documentation
Download This Template

```
<div class="header-menu" role="menu">
```

Home
Features
Documentation
Download This Template

```
 <ul id="main-menu-nav" role="menubar">
```

Home
Features
Documentation
Download This Template

```
<ul id="main-menu-nav" role="menubar">
```

Home

```
<li>
```

Features

```
<li class="has-sub">
```

Documentation

```
<li class="has-sub">
```

How can I be correcting these critical accessibility errors? . thanks

I've started a web developer course but I'm still at the very beginning of HTML. Sorry if I wasn't very clear.

I tried to add role='menu' in mobile menu and header menu but it didn't work.

Comment: `<b:` et al is not standard HTML. You need to tag whatever that is from.